# cant find css element path to change the position of chat window which comes from iframe

Tags: css, iframe, element, move

so i have one issue . on site there is live help chat button , one you click icon you must enter your details and than live agent will assist you . it comes from iframe  link. i want to change this live window which comes on site after clicking the chat icon . but i have only access via css.

so guys i want to move live chat window which comes after clicking the chat icon from one corner to another corner thats all. and again only via css

`<iframe src="https://chat.link" allowfullscreen="true" allow="microphone; camera" tabindex="0" class="i-embedded-form" id="ifb_d5n2p7sg_576" style="display: block; position: fixed; border: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 350px; height: 500px; z-index: 999997; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; margin-left: 2px;" title="Contact form window"></iframe`

this is first iframe there is two of them dont know why

here is second

`<iframe src="https://chat.link" allowfullscreen="true" allow="microphone; camera" tabindex="-1" class="i-embedded-chat" id="icb_d5n2p7sg_576" style="display: none; position: fixed; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>`

i tried alomost all elements but nothing changed after clicking icon chat windows appears in same place. searched a lost but could not find anything

Comment: You can't influence how an iframe styles things (unless you have control of that iframe of course). Is that what you are needing to do?

Comment: yes. i have to edit live support button. to move to another corner of site which comes from iframe. but i can only do this with css